# Can I use Objects over the Switch Statement?

Tags: javascript, ajax, switch-statement, javascript-objects

I want to know if there is an alternative way of making this Switch Statement more efficient with perhaps less code?

I've heard about the Objects is better and cleaner and there's no need of using the break anymore. How can I use it properly?

Thanks.

code here - https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/cq1g5dyt/4/

```js
$.each(response.weather, function(index) { //retrieve data
      let icon;
      switch (response.weather[index].currentConditions) { //switch case for icons
        case "Cloud":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/cloud.png" alt="cloud" width="22px"/>';
          break;
        case "Hail":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/hail.png" alt="hail" width="22px"/>';
          break;
        case "Heavy Cloud":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/heavy cloud.png" alt="heavy-clouds" width="22px"/>';
          break;
        case "Heavy Rain":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/heavy rain.png" alt="heavy-rain" width="22px"/>';
          break;
        case "Rain":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/rain.png" alt="rain" width="22px"/>';
          break;
        case "Sleet":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/sleet.png" alt="sleet" width="22px"/>';
          break;
        case "Snow":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/snow.png" alt="snow" width="22px"/>';
          break;
        case "Sun":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/sun.png" alt="sun" width="22px"/>';
          break;
        case "Sun and Clouds":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/sun and cloud.png" alt="sun-clouds" width="22px"/>';
          break
        case "Thunderstorm":
          icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/thunderstorm.png" alt="thunderstorm" width="22px"/>';
          break;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can build a dictionary of weather types.

```
/** @typedef {{file: string, label: string}} WeatherEntry */
/** @typedef {[key: string]: WeatherEntry} WeatherMap */

/** @type {WeatherMap} */
const weather = {
    "Cloud": {
        "file": "cloud.png",
        "label": "cloud"
    },
    // ...
};
```

Then use that:

```
const entry = weather[response.weather[index].currentConditions];
let icon = `<img src="./weather_icons/${entry.file}" alt="${entry.label}" width="22px" />`;
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. You may want to add a check for `if( !entry)` and provide some kind of default fallback if the condition you get isn't one in your list.

Comment: You should also move the `const weather = ...` part outside of the loop. Put it at the top of the script, outside any blocks, so it's only defined once and re-used forever.

Comment: I moved the const weather to the top of the script outside of the loop. I tried to add the if(!entry) but I'm not sure if I did correctly. I am definitely missing something link - https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/cq1g5dyt/9/

Answer (score 0):

Each weather condition has three unique strings associated with it: the string returned by the API, the image filename, and the image `alt`. You can do this concisely using an object indexed by API response string, where each value is either another object or array:

```
const weatherStrings = {
  Cloud: ['cloud', 'cloud',
  Hail: ['hail', 'hail'],
  'Heavy Cloud': ['heavy cloud', 'heavy-clouds'],
  // ...
}

// ...

success: function(response) {
  for (const item of response.weather) {
    const [filename, alt] = weatherStrings[item.currentConditions];
    const icon = `<img src="./weather_icons/${filename}.png" alt="${alt}" width="22px">`;
    // ...
  }
```

If possible, you can make things shorter and more consistent by changing your backend to have the same filename as the `currentConditions` string - eg, change `cloud.png`'s filename to `Cloud.png`, and `heavy rain.png` to `Heavy Rain.png`. Then the value for each weather string only needs to be the `alt` string:

```
const altsByCurrentConditions = {
  Cloud: 'cloud',
  Hail: 'hail',
  'Heavy Cloud': 'heavy-clouds',
  // ...
}

// ...

success: function(response) {
  for (const item of response.weather) {
    const alt = altsByCurrentConditions[item.currentConditions];
    const icon = `<img src="./weather_icons/${item.currentConditions}.png" alt="${alt}" width="22px">`;
    // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be better solution for you

```
$.each(response.weather, function (index) { //retrieve data
    let icon;
    let currentCondition = response.weather[index].currentConditions.toLowerCase();
    icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/${currentCondition}.png" 
    alt="${currentCondition}" width="22px"/>'; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not all conditions map quite so simply as `toLowerCase`, otherwise this would indeed be a good solution.